# Get string's Sql Server nvarchar(255) bytes in Java

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, types, java-8

I am trying to replicate a legacy Sql Server hash algorithm in Java. The issue is that this algorithm uses HashBytes(MD5) which gives different results depending on the type that the string is that I am hashing.

So at a minimum, it seems that I need to know how to get the bytes of a string as an nvarchar(255) in java.

I realize I could just do this as a sql select in Java but I am looking for a way to not do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    byte[] b = str.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
    java.security.MessageDigest md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    return javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(md.digest(b));
```

This gives me the same hash as sql server `HASHBYTES('MD5',...)` on some `nvarchar(255)`. The key seems to be `UTF-16LE`.